# XSLT - Exclude Node If It Contains Invalid Data

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to check the value of a child node and include it in the transformed XML only if it it's value isn't -1. Below is a sample of the input xml.

```
<root>
   <a>-1</a>
   <b>valid</b>
   <c>valid</c>
   <d>valid</d>
</root>
```

And the relevant section of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="/a != -1">
          <xsl:value-of select="*"></xsl:value-of>     
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="*[not(a)]"></xsl:value-of>
     </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Elements b through c are permitted to have values of -1, so I need to check the `<a>` element for that value specifically, and only it should be excluded. Currently I do the -1 check in a choose block, and try to exclude it by using `<xsl:value-of select="*[not(a)]"></xsl:value-of>`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is "year"?

Comment: Sorry it should've been not(a). I made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard recursive descent processing model using `xsl:apply-templates`, then you just need a do-nothing rule

```
<xsl:template match="a[.=-1]"/>
```

to exclude these elements.

If you're using some other processing model then you need to show us your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Michael. I edited the question to include my section of the XSLT. That section is inside of another element that doesn't allow having <xsl:template> as a child. Any other ideas how I might be able to achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid your XSLT fragment looks all wrong to me. I can't see where it fits into the stylesheet as a whole, but the logic makes no sense to me. The proper way to tackle this in XSLT is to write an identity template rule that matches everything and copies it recursively, and then further template rules for elements where you want different behaviour, such as the one in my answer.